# Отключается вк бот на хостинге pythonanywhere.com

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, бот, вконтакте, хостинг

Написал бота на питоне и залил на хостинг python.anywhere.com. Проработав, несколько дней он отключается. В консоле высвечивается командная строка. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

PA в первую очередь расчитан на хостинг, а не как полноценный vps. Действия в консоли и tasks тратят процессорное время и нет гарантии, что консоли будут всегда открыты.

Попробуйте сделать task, который будет запускаться каждый день и завершаться перед следующим запуском (при условии, что вы не потратите процессорное время). На платных аккаунтах есть почасовой запуск задач и постоянно запущенные задачи.